# Splitting an OSGi console into input and output consoles

Tags: console, osgi, gogo-shell

I am wondering if it is somehow possible to have an OSGi environment with GoGo shell running with different consoles for input and output.

It is not very handy to write gogo commands into a console where your system is logging a lot of data.

Is there a good solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of solutions for your question.

- You can use the [telnet](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-remote-shell.html) or [ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590137/apache-felix-shell-with-ssh) interface to gogo. Apache Felix provides both in separate bundles.
- Gogo registers a CommandProcessor from which you can make a CommandSession by supplying an Input and Output Stream. It is quite easy to make a small Java Swing program that acts as a shell
- Stop logging so much :-)